# Converse of "positive sequence converges to positive limit"

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is well known, and not hard to prove, that if a convergent real sequence $(x_n)$ is eventually positive (i.e. there is some $K$ for which $n > K \Rightarrow x_n > 0$), then the limit to which it converges must be non-negative. I am interested in whether the converse is true: that is, if we know that $(x_n)$ converges to a non-negative limit, then is it true that there exists $K$ with the property stated above?

Comment: Why do you think if a convergent sequence is eventually positive the limit is positive?  If you know why that must be true, I think you should be able to answer your own question.

Comment: You probably mis-quoted the "well known and not hard to prove" statement in the first sentence, since it's false.

Comment: Consider $x_n=1/n$, which is convergent and (eventually) positive but does not have a positive limit.

Comment: I have corrected "positive" to "non-negative" - apologies for any confusion.

Comment: If it converges to $0$ then it most certainly does necessarily become eventually positive! Consider $\lim -\frac 1n$ which is *never* non-negative and never positive.  But if $\lim a_n = a > 0$ is positive then ... well, I *really* encourage you to work this out yourself.  All of this statement follow directly from definitions of convergence and *very* simple and common sensical observation.

Comment: Here is the basic fact. A positive number has a neighborhood consisting of positive numbers only. A negative number has a neighborhood consisting of negative numbers only. But every neighborhood of $0$ contains both positive and negative numbers. So when your limit is $0$ one can't give guarantee about sign of the sequence / function converging to $0$. The statement above remains true if the numbers are restricted to rationals so that it is related to the way order relations work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(x_n)$ converges to a strictly positive limit $x$, then the terms of the sequence must eventually become positive. By definition of convergence, there is a $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n - x| < x$ for all $n \geq K$ (using $x$, which is greater than zero, as the "$\varepsilon$"). In particular, this implies that for all $n \geq K$, we have $-(x_n - x) < x$, or equivalently, $x_n > 0$.

However, if a sequence converges to zero then it need not be eventually positive.

Comment: My question is why must the terms eventually become positive?

Comment: @Prasiortle I've added some details to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x_n)$ converges to $x(> 0)$. i.e.,

For a given $\epsilon>0, \hspace{1mm}\exists K\in \Bbb{N}$ , such that $\forall n\geq K, x_{n}\in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$. This works for any $\epsilon>0$.

Let the given $\epsilon:=x>0 \implies \exists K\in \Bbb{N}$ , such that $\forall n\geq K, x_{n}\in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)=(0,2x)$ OR $0<x_{n}<2x$.

Hence, there exists a $K$ for which $x_{k}>0$ for all $n\geq K$.

Comment: In the first paragraph you say $x \geq 0$. But in the this paragraph you are assuming $x > 0$. (The claim is in fact false if $x = 0$.)

Comment: @Bungo you're right. For $x_{n} \rightarrow 0$, must it be that $|x_{n}| \rightarrow 0$, and not that $x_{n}>0$

Comment: edited: $x$ ($>0$)

Answer (score 0):

Well the big picture is if $\lim a_n \to a > 0$ then eventually the distance between $a_n$ and $a$ will get very small and it will eventually become smaller than $a$ itself and if $a_n$ is closer to $a$ then $a$ is to $0$ then $a_n$ must be positive (if $a_n \le 0$ then $a_n$ would be *at least* as far away as $a$ is from $0$).

Can you prove it formally with the definition?

> $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = a$ means that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $K$ so that whenever $n > K$ then $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$.

What should we choose $\epsilon$ to be to make $a_n$ closer to $a$ than $a$ is to $0$?

> If $a > 0$ what if we choose  $\epsilon \le a$?  Then there is a $K$ so that whenever $n > K$ then $|a_n - a| < \epsilon \le a$.  So $-a < a_n - a < a$ so $0 < a_n < 2a$.  So $a_n>0$ for all $n >K$.